# Python pafy global not working across a function-call boundary

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables, instance, pafy

Okay, I was trying to make a simple script to download youtube videos using [`pafy`](http://pythonhosted.org/Pafy/). Currently I have a problem with the global variable `video` which I use to store what `pafy.new('url')` returns. Here's the two functions I use:

```
video = {};

def downloadVideo():

    options = {};
    options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\';
    options['mustexist'] = False;
    options['title'] = 'Download folder';

    dir_path = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(**options);
    global video;
    video.getbest(preftype="mp4").download(quiet=True, filepath=dir_path);

def get():
    url = url_entry.get();

    if url == '':
        return

    global video;
    video = pafy.new(url);

    # Some code to display video info
```

First I use `get()` function to get the video from `url_entry` which is a tkinter Entry widget. So far so good, but when I call `downloadVideo()` I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  Rather than using globals, change `get` to `return video` at the end, and change `downloadVideo` to take a parameter: `downloadVideo(video)`.  That way you don't have to worry about local vs. global and you can find other issues.  I'm guessing the code that calls `get` and `downloadVideo` modifies `video` so that `getbest(...)` returns None, whence the error.

Comment: @cxw Python 3. Btw, the code that calls `get()` and `downloadVideo()` doesn't modify `video`.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I stand by my first comment: don't use globals.  Other than that, I'm not seeing any obvious problems.  If you turn off the globals and still have problems, update the question with the new code and give me a shout.

Comment: @cxw Thanks man I 'll give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem in this line:

```
video.getbest(preftype="mp4").download(quiet=True, filepath=dir_path);
```

This:

```
video.getbest(preftype="mp4")
```

actually returned a `NoneType` object since it didn't contain any `mp4` stream. So, it's not exactly a problem, it's just something I should check before calling `download()`. Now I just get all the streams `video.streams` and download what I need or just let it download the best available `video.getbest().download()`.